# OpenGL ES 2.0 on the Android Emulator isn't working

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

In [the docs for OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android](https://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html), it states:

```
Caution: OpenGL ES 2.0 is currently not supported by the Android Emulator. You must have a physical test device running Android 2.2 (API Level 8) or higher in order to run and test the example code in this tutorial.
```

However, this, (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html) states:

```
As a bonus, since we’re now supporting OpenGL ES 2.0, your OpenGL games can now run inside the emulator.
```

However, I tried to use OpenGL ES 2.0 on the emulator and it errors out, saying that OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported on the device (emulator)>

The VM is running as an accelerated Intel Atom x86 processor, and I have GPU Emulation set to "yes".

I'm using API Level 15, and the latest revision of the SDK (19), on Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit.

My CPU is: Intel Core i7-2670QM, and I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560M.

Any ideas? Should it be working? If so, how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error message I was seeing was something that the 3d framework I was using (Rajawali) was outputting. OpenGL ES 2.0 works fine on the emulator, however, the emulator doesn't report that it's supported. I removed the check and it worked fine.

Comment: can u plese tell me what u actually did. please mention the steps.i am getting the same error By the [user:user1322495](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1322495/user1322495)

Comment: If you're using Rajawali, I already submitted a patch to fix it...however, I'm pretty sure that as of now, it hasn't been packaged into a new JAR...you'll have to do that yourself. If you're not using Rajawali, well, I can't help you, you'll just have to find and disable the OpenGL ES 2.0 compatibility code yourself.